# Four Dimensional Noise Texture for Displace

Tags: displacement

I am moving a noise texture through a mesh for displacement and I want to know where the 4D option would be for the texture. When I move the noise, it moves across X - Y, but I also want it to move across Z. Is this possible?

Comment: you can move it on Z with the Mapping location values. The W option is used to transform the noise shape

Comment: Thanks! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move it on *Z* with the *Mapping* node location values. The *W* option is used to transform the noise shape through time.